# How to bind different entities with NSTableView and NSTabView?

Tags: objective-c, nstableview, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller, nstabview

I have an `NSArrayController` which handles entities of `GeometryShape`.
`GeometryShape` has: `name`, `type`, `color`.
`LineShape` is a `GeometryShape` and has: `beginPositionX`, `beginPositionY`, `endPositionX`, `endPositionY`.
`CircleShape` is a `GeometryShape` and has: `positionX`, `positionY`, `radius`.

The `NSTableView` shows all inserted shapes in the `NSArrayController`, where each column is bound with `arrangedObjects` & the key name.

When I select a line shape, its properties are displayed in the Line tab - which is the default tab.

Now if I select a circle shape, I want the Circle tab to be selected and the circles properties to be displayed.

…and so depending on which shape type I select the corresponding tab will be selected and display the corresponding shape properties.

How may I achieve this excellent :) model?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd want to implement a NSTableViewDelegate and programmatically select the appropriate tab within an implementation of `tableViewSelectionDidChange:`  When the selection changes, you just grab the tabView's IBOutlet and assign a new selectedIndex based on the arrayController's selection.

Alternately, you could bind the value of the tabView's selectedIndex to the array controller's selection, but you would need a custom value transformer that converted from the selection `id` to an `NSUInteger` that reflects the appropriate class.

In either implementation, you're writing code using `isKindOfClass` and mapping to an integer.

You may also be able to bind the tab view's selectedLabel to the array controller keypath of `selection.class` but I'm guessing you still would need a valuetransformer wrapping `NSStringFromClass()` as described in the [`NSValueTransformer` docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSValueTransformer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  I'm not totally certain there's a completely non-code way of transforming the class to a string you could bind the selectedLabel to, though.

Personally, I don't love implementing the custom value transformer because you're writing code to allow implementing behavior buried in IB... all to avoid writing code that could live in a custom tableview delegate.